# Quick and easy macro to delete a single cell based on text criteria.

Tags: excel, vba

i just need to delete a single cell using a button.

So I am working on a project where by the user just hits a button and the spreadsheet prints based on the amount of data they put in. However we have one merged cell where they can put data in but if they dont enter any data, we need the cell to be empty. The snipped of code im using is below. The entire project is below that snippet for reference.

```
Range("B15:E19").Select
        If Range("B15:E19") = "Enter and special posting instruction here." Then
        Range("B15:E19").ClearContents
        End If
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub LastRowInOneColumn()

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Worksheets("SIF Sheet")

    With MySheet

        Dim xLastRow As Long
        xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Select Case True

            Case xLastRow > 21 And xLastRow < 46

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=1

            Case xLastRow > 46 And xLastRow < 97

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=2

            Case xLastRow > 98 And xLastRow < 149

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=3

            Case xLastRow > 150 And xLastRow < 201

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=4

            Case xLastRow > 202 And xLastRow < 253

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=5

            Case xLastRow > 254 And xLastRow < 305

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=6

            Case xLastRow > 306 And xLastRow < 357

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=7

            Case xLastRow > 358 And xLastRow < 409

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=8

            Case xLastRow > 410 And xLastRow < 461

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=9

            Case xLastRow > 462 And xLastRow < 513

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=10

        End Select




    End With

        Range("B15:E19").Select
        If Range("B15:E19") = "Enter and special posting instruction here." Then
        Range("B15:E19").ClearContents
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry should have probably said, what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following. Just reference the top left of the merged range and set the value to ""

```
    If Range("B15").Value = "Enter and special posting instruction here." Then
          Range("B15").Value = ""
    End If
```

Hope that helps

Caleeco

Comment: See thats what I thought too but then I got an error message about it being a merged cell. Maybe I mistyped something. Let me try that quick,

Comment: So the good news is no merged cell error, the bad news the text was still there when we printed. So im going to try other code snipped and see what happens.

Comment: I think you've already spotted it, but yes you need to move the code up in the macro to execute before the Print :)

Comment: I also figured out that text in the cell was in quotations. Literally in quotations and so the code was trying to find the text without quotations so i removed them from the cell and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 2):

How About:

```
    If Range("B15") = "Enter and special posting instruction here." Then
        Range("B15:E19").ClearContents
    End If
```

Comment: We're testing Calicos snippet right now on multiple computers. Looks like its working but I want to make sure first.

Comment: Yes, his will work just fine also - I didn't see it when I posted mine.
Your only problem was the first B15:E19, you only need B15 and you do not need to select the cell first as your code did.
Also, it looks like you should add this before the print command.

Comment: OMG I feel like such an idiot. Thats why its not working. Im executing it after the print command.